# Using TLS V1.1/V 1.2 with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection

In my application, I am using `NSURLConnection` to make network calls. However, it uses `SSL V3` by default; but I need to use `TLS V1.1/1.2` with `NSURLConnection`.

I have gone through several sources available online, but none of them proved to be useful. Also, there seems no way I can stop NSURLConnection from using SSL V3. Is there a way using which `NSURLConnection` can be forced to use `TLS V1.1/1.2`, or will I have to alter my code to use `CFStream` APIs or the `SecureTransport` APIs provided by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

From [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

Excerpt fron te document:

> Default Behavior
>
> All connections using the NSURLConnection, CFURL, or NSURLSession APIs use App Transport Security default behavior in apps built for iOS 9.0 or later, and OS X 10.11 or later. Connections that do not follow the requirements will fail.
>
> The App Transport Security requirements:
> The server must support at least Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol version 1.2.